# Fastest Way to update no duplicate field into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a big csv file with 130M of lines with columns(NAME, date)

I want to import/update into Mongodb without any duplicate (name).

I try to update with pymongo :

```
today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
s = '.'

for line in open('input.csv', "r"):
        remove = line.rstrip()
        name = remove.lower()
        collection.update({"name": name},{"$set": {"zone_date": today}}, upsert = True)
```

It's so slow, then i try to import with importmongo with the --uperfield option :

```
mongoimport -d mydatabase -c name --type csv --fields name,zone_date --upsertFields name --file input.csv
```

But both methods are very slow.
Do you know the best way to improve speed of update a huge dataset ?

Comment: how long is slow? you are updating 130M lines

Comment: 20-24h for 130M lines with a SSD / 24Go dedicated Server

Answer (score 0):

Other than working in batches (of say, 1M lines), if you want to use PyMongo, you can put the final records in a list and insert them all together with insert_many.

```
records = [] 

with open('input.csv') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        remove = line.rstrip()
        name = remove.lower()
        records.append({"name": name, "zone_date": today})

# don't insert until the end 
collection.insert_many(records, upsert = True)
```

That will speed up things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the "upsert = True" is not allowed on insert_many operation